# Code what/that matters

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, grammaticality-in-context, relative-pronouns

Saw an advertisement from Grammarly, a spell checker, where they humbly write: **Code what matters**.

It doesn’t seem right to me, although I’m not a native speaker, might be wrong here.

I feel like it should be **Code that matters**, am I wrong?

Can someone please explain the difference between **what** and **that**?

Answer (score 2):

They have different meanings.

In "code what matters", code is an imperative verb. It is similar to saying, "You should only code what is important", or "Only code things that have substantial/considerable effects".

In "code that matters", code is a noun. It means "code that has importance", or "code of importance", or "code that has substantial effects". You might use it by saying: "Only produce code that matters!" Or in a slogan: "Create code that matters!"